# iphone installing Ad Hoc Distribution

Tags: iphone

I try to install my app. to client's iphone via "Ad Hoc Distribution". When i sync, I got this type of error:

"The application is not installed on iphone because it is not signed"

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you missed a step in the provisioning process

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW3

Answer (score 0):

yaa i think u are using same application binary u made to upload it on app store.

Both process are Different. u have to make new profile for ad hoc distribution and install that profile to device also.