# Testing for Ad Hoc Distribution on the Developing device

Tags: iphone, ipad, code-signing, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to create my app's build using `Ad Hoc Distribution profile`. i'm dead sure that the `provision profile` is correct and have the client `DeviceID` added in it. I also have the `Entitlements.plist` in my project.

Also the code is Signed at the Target level with Ad Hoc Distribution Profile.

I'm sending both the provision profile as well as the app.ipa file, but the client still complains that he cannot install the build through itunes and it fires the error :

**The Application "" was not installed on the iPhone "" because the signer is not valid.**

I've tried :

1.[Signer not valid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857414/signer-not-valid-error)

2.[signer is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568641/signer-is-not-valid)

3.http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/68731-signer-not-valid-error.html

4.[iphone installing Ad Hoc Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646839/iphone-installing-ad-hoc-distribution)

I have only 1 device and i use it for development. I've deleted all the profiles and apps as well and then tried to install the app from itunes and it installed successfully.

**But,It does not work for my Client. So how can i test this build before sending it to the client???**

Comment: send no. 1 link to your client.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try two things:

- Build and archive the app -> head to the organizer -> share the app, signing it with your distribution cert + ad hoc provisioning profile
- Make sure you've selected the ad hoc provisioning profile in the build settings of **both** the project and the target settings for the release configuration -> build using build configuration -> locate build product -> send build product + provisioning profile to your client

Personally, I'd absolutely recommend the first option. It is cleaner, because you don't need to adjust the build settings and rebuild your app each time you're adding a new device to your provisioning profile. Additionally, it will allow you to send your client one handy .ipa file instead of build + profile and it enable you to use services like [Testflight](http://www.testflightapp.com).

If you're (for whatever reason...) stuck with the second option however, keep in mind that each time you modify a provisioning profile, its ID will change. This means you will need to select it again in the project and build settings, even if it **appears** like the proper profile is still selected!!